# Will my Canon CanoScan 500F scanner work with Lion?

Tags: macos, scanning, image-capture

I'm getting a lot of TWAINBridge errors in the console and Image Capture won't scan documents like it did last week (on 10.6.8 Snow Leopard).

```
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- p
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- s
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- n
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- _
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 0
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- _
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 5
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 4
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 0
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 8
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 0
7/23/11 1:46:18.822 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/TWAINBridge.app/Contents/MacOS/TWAINBridge: illegal option -- 4
7/23/11 2:20:05.051 PM [0x0-0x84084].com.apple.TWAINBridge: ImageIO: <ERROR>  JPEG Application transferred too few scanlines
```

I checked the canon site - and the [latest drivers are only for 10.6](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/scanners/canoscan_series/canoscan_lide_500f#DriversAndSoftware) - no mention is made of this scanner on the [Canon list of devices that work with Lion](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/macosx_lion?page_left_nav=division_1).

I have rebooted twice, checked the cables. I'm hoping someone can point out something I may have missed that might get things going for me.

If not, it's off to the used market with some Core Duo macs and all my rosetta software!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some old saved settings were causing the scanner to hang indefinitely  - pressing scan over and over wasn't working.

I pressed the show details button a few times but didn't realize things were working slowly in the background. After a minute or so - I was able to get into the details, change some settings, and it has been working well.

[image]
Those TWAIN errors are not logging now either. Life is good again in Lion scan land.